# Touchpad is only working when entered startup menu

Tags: touchpad, bios, hp

I am trying to figure out what may be the cause that a touchpad on my hp notebook is working only if I enter startup menu (whether by pressing esc at startup or from grub) and by adding `i8042.nopnp` to the kernel command line. Both operations are necessary since merely adding i8042 parameter does make the touchpad discoverable but unresponsive and just entering the menu does not make anything to my knowledge. Multiple solutions that I have found (most notably adding other `i8042.xxx` parameters) gave no positive results whatsoever (literally, neither `xinput` nor `dmesg` outputs have not changed).
By startup menu I mean a dialog where I can choose whether to open bios setup, change boot order, boot from network, launch UEFI diagnostics tool etc.

My notebook's model is HP 15s-eq1017nw with a mobile Ryzen APU (4500U if it matters), no discrete GPU. The firmware versions I have tested multiple distros on (specifically: Ubuntu 21.10 and 20.04 LTS, Linux MX 21 both "ahs" and standard, and the current Manjaro ) are F.34 Rev.A and F.54 Rev.A.

Before going into `dmesg` and `xinput` outputs I would like to emphasize that I have found my "solution" by a mere coincidence so there is no know-how behind it.

Just for the record, bluetooth, wifi, keyboard and the display have worked out of the box. It is just the touchpad that is tricky.

`dmesg` output when the touchpad is working (i.e. when I add `i8042.nopnp` to the kernel options and enter the bios setup):
https://pastebin.com/ZHu1iSp4

`dmesg` output when I just add the `i8042.nopnp` but skip entering the bios setup:
https://pastebin.com/mxWX9CpL

Both outputs were made just after logining in.

The touchpad is working fine on Windows 10 (including during its installation) and is recognized as an Elantech touchpad (both on W10 and Linux)

Finally, xinput outputs:
(`xinput` when it is working)

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD Touchpad            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD Mouse               id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

(`xinput` when the touchpad is detected but it does not move the cursor, i.e. when I don't enter the bios setup)

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP TrueVision HD Camera: HP Tru           id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HP WMI hotkeys                            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

## Update 1

I just checked what does grub do when it enters the startup menu and it invokes the `fwsetup` command.

I wonder what happens when a machine enters this menu/state since this action makes touchpad not only discoverable but also working.

And before anyone asks, waiting before launching Linux does solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your first pastebin (working state) includes these lines:

```
[    1.817897] input: ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN071A:00/0018:04F3:30FD.0001/input/input6
[    1.817941] input: ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN071A:00/0018:04F3:30FD.0001/input/input8
[    1.817968] hid-generic 0018:04F3:30FD.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD] on i2c-ELAN071A:00
```

and later:

```
[    3.788331] input: ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD Mouse as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN071A:00/0018:04F3:30FD.0001/input/input13
[    3.788469] input: ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD Touchpad as /devices/platform/AMDI0010:03/i2c-1/i2c-ELAN071A:00/0018:04F3:30FD.0001/input/input15
[    3.788561] hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:30FD.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN071A:00 04F3:30FD] on i2c-ELAN071A:00
```

These lines are all missing in the failing case.

This indicates the touchpad is one of the newer `i2c`-connected ones: basically, the touchpad also provides classic PS/2-mouse-like functionality for compatibility, but the full functionality (e.g. multitouch) is only reachable using the i2c interface.

Unfortunately, the I2C-HID specification tends to be poorly implemented, requiring device-specific quirks. See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033033/elantech-touchpad-does-not-work-i2c-hid

You could try `modprobe elan_i2c`, `modprobe i2c_hid` and/or `modprobe hid-multitouch` and see if they make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but none of the provided commands make touchpad working if I won't go into bios setup first.